# How do I beautify (auto-format) a piece of code in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, ide, spyder

How can I select a piece of code and apply auto-format, aka beautification to it?

I especially mean correctly indenting lists broken into several lines, parentheses and square brackets.

Auto-indent does nothing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nowadays (or at least in Spyder v5), Spyder includes autopep8 directly in the GUI and has an option of automatic formatting (as requested in the original question).

Simply go to `Tools > Preferences` then choose `Completion and linting > Code style and formatting`. There, toggle on `Enable code style linting` and `Autoformat files on save`.

Now when you save your file, Spyder will beautify your code, when it can infer what to do. This should include adding missing whitespaces after commas or around operators, removing whitespaces in empty lines or missing new lines to separate functions, just to name a few.

Answer (score 6):

One possible solution is to use this plugin:
[autopep8 for Spyder](https://github.com/Nodd/spyder_autopep8)

Although since Python is a language where code functionality depends on the amount of whitespace, beautification tools can never really format the code in an unified way.

Unfortunately, autopep8 does not solve code formatting conventions that are violated (as indicated by Pylint).

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>ctrl + alt + l</kbd> or right click and `"format line..."`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to also check out [Black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)